# database record that can belong to one or another table in postgres

Tags: postgresql, database-design, foreign-keys

I am looking for some solution for my next use-case in postgres:

I have a table (tasks) that can belong to a user (another table) or a company (another table), it should belong to one of the two tables, that means that I should have nullable foreign keys but also I should check that on Insert then one and only one of those should be filled. How can I make this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding nullable columns (lets say `user_id` and `company_id`) with corresponding `FOREIGN KEY` is correct.

You can add a check-constraint like this (to do it in the `CREATE TABLE` statement, you can list it "like a column" and start at `CONSTRAINT`):

```sql
ALTER TABLE tasks ADD CONSTRAINT tasks_fk_check
    CHECK (
        (user_id IS NOT NULL AND company_id IS NULL)
        OR
        (user_id IS NULL AND company_id IS NOT NULL)
    )
;
```

There are some other possibilities like `(user_id IS NULL) <> (company_id IS NULL)` to express the `XOR` property. You can choose them as condition as well.

For further information, have a look into the documentation:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function that counts the number of null values in a VARIADAC parameter list. Then create a check constraint accessing that function.  
 
If this is an isolated use case then this is not necessary the best approach, but it is a generalized approach for requiring a certain number of nulls from a set of columns.

```
--setup  create test table
create table task( id serial, user_id integer, company_id integer);


-- create function to count number of nulls in VARIADIC parameter
create or replace function num_of_nulls(VARIADIC integer[])
returns bigint
language sql immutable
as $$
    with each_item as (select unnest($1) itm)
    select sum(case when itm is null then 1 else 0 end) from each_item;
  $$;

-- add check constraint
alter table task add constraint one_and_only_one_must_be_null check (num_of_nulls(user_id,company_id) = 1);

-- test
-- valid 
insert into task(user_id,company_id)
values (1,null), (null,1); 

select * from task;     

-- invalid (must be run separately)
insert into task(user_id,company_id)
values (null,null);

insert into task(user_id,company_id)
values (2,2);
```

Comment: You don't need to write such a function, it's already built-in: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISON-FUNC-TABLE

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Even better. Thought I had seem something some time ago, but couldn't find it. Thanks